# Формат времени Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, ldap

Как декодировать такой("130491974458250423") формат времени на python?
P.S. Если что, это - pwdLastSet, полученный через ldapsearch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно документации, pwdLastSet возвращает количество 100-наносекундных интервалов с момента 1 января 1601 года.

Соответственно, если я ничего не напутал, то к питоновскому времени это нужно приводить так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s = "130491974458250423"

start_epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
koef = 1e7  # количество 100-наносекундных интервалов в одной секунде
seconds = float(s) / koef

result = start_epoch + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print(result)
```